# May I bind Mission Control's next and previous space to ctrl+mousewheel?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse, mission-control

May I bind Mission Control's next and previous space to `ctrl`+`mousewheelup` and `ctrl`+`mousewheeldown`?

Using the system settings apparently I can't, so I'm wondering if there's another non-invasive way? (such as manually editing a config file, for instance)

OSX 10.8, in case this matters.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.net/). It's a free app that allows you to bind a large number of system actions to the controls on your mouse, including Mission Control and changing spaces. I have a Magic Mouse, so I'm not 100% sure that it will work with a normal mouse scroll wheel, but I'm fairly certain that it will.

Comment: Nice try, but apparently it doesn't allow me to bind the mouse wheel :/

Comment: Oh well. I guess it only works for the mouse buttons, and not actually moving the scroll wheel. Sorry.